# How to do ripple effect in figma

Tags: figma, ripple-effect

I am trying to make ripple animation but it's not playing. Whenever I want to play it, it shows that a prototype must be have at least one frame.

Although I made the Design with 3 frames then why ? Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: To get the best help on Stack Overflow, please show your trial work. It helps us understand the issue and provide more relevant solutions. This not only helps us understand your issue better but also ensures that others who come across your question can learn from it.